# Restarting a failed/stalled stream during bootstrap of new node

Tags: datastax-enterprise

We are trying to add a new Solr node to our cluster:

**DC Cassandra**

- Cassandra node 1

**DC Solr**

- Solr node 1 <-- new node (actually, a replacement for an old node)
- Solr node 2
- Solr node 3
- Solr node 4
- Solr node 5

During the bootstrap process:

1. The stream from node 3 to node 1 failed with an exception:

   > ERROR [STREAM-OUT-/IP_OF_NODE1] 2014-04-01 01:14:40,887 CassandraDaemon.java (line 196) Exception in thread Thread[STREAM-OUT-/IP_OF_NODE1,5,main]
   >   java.lang.NullPointerException
   >   at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.ConnectionHandler$MessageHandler.signalCloseDone(ConnectionHandler.java:249)
   >   at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.ConnectionHandler$OutgoingMessageHandler.run(ConnectionHandler.java:375)
   >   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
2. The stream from node 4 to node 1 never started. The last relevant line in node 4's system.log is:

   > Received streaming plan for Bootstrap.

   It should have been followed by:

   > Prepare completed. Receiving 0 files(0 bytes), sending x files(y bytes)

It seems that the bootstrap process is now stalled because the data file sizes are not changing anymore. How can I force those streams to be retried?

**EDIT:**

I restarted all nodes today in an attempt to force new node to retry the bootstrap process. Unfortunately, it encountered some stream failures again. This time, the exception **in node 1** is as follows:

```
WARN [STREAM-IN-/IP_OF_NODE3] 2014-04-06 20:48:17,963 StreamSession.java (line 532) [Stream #c84effb0-bda9-11e3-a07d-89325af2f6bf] Retrying for following error
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/cassandra/data/my_keyspace/my_table/my_keyspace-my_table-tmp-jb-1209-Data.db (Too many open files)
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.SequentialWriter.<init>(SequentialWriter.java:75)
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.CompressedSequentialWriter.<init>(CompressedSequentialWriter.java:71)
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.CompressedSequentialWriter.open(CompressedSequentialWriter.java:42)
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableWriter.<init>(SSTableWriter.java:107)
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableWriter.<init>(SSTableWriter.java:60)
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamReader.createWriter(StreamReader.java:111)
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.compress.CompressedStreamReader.read(CompressedStreamReader.java:65)
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.messages.IncomingFileMessage$1.deserialize(IncomingFileMessage.java:47)
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.messages.IncomingFileMessage$1.deserialize(IncomingFileMessage.java:37)
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.messages.StreamMessage.deserialize(StreamMessage.java:55)
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.ConnectionHandler$IncomingMessageHandler.run(ConnectionHandler.java:283)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/cassandra/data/my_keyspace/my_table/my_keyspace-my_table-tmp-jb-1209-Data.db (Too many open files)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:233)
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.SequentialWriter.<init>(SequentialWriter.java:71)
ERROR [STREAM-IN-/78.46.63.218] 2014-04-06 20:48:17,964 StreamSession.java (line 418) [Stream #c84effb0-bda9-11e3-a07d-89325af2f6bf] Streaming error occurred
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown type 0
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.messages.StreamMessage$Type.get(StreamMessage.java:89)
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.messages.StreamMessage.deserialize(StreamMessage.java:54)
    at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.ConnectionHandler$IncomingMessageHandler.run(ConnectionHandler.java:283)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

There are tons of similar errors in the log. e.g.:

```
ERROR [CompactionExecutor:129] 2014-04-06 20:50:06,401 CassandraDaemon.java (line 196) Exception in thread Thread[CompactionExecutor:129,1,main]
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/cassandra/data/my_keyspace/my_table/my_keyspace-my_table-jb-51-Data.db (Too many open files)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.pager.QueryPagers$1.next(QueryPagers.java:154)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.pager.QueryPagers$1.next(QueryPagers.java:137)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.Keyspace.indexRow(Keyspace.java:400)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.index.SecondaryIndexBuilder.build(SecondaryIndexBuilder.java:62)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.CompactionManager$9.run(CompactionManager.java:833)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/cassandra/data/my_keyspace/my_table/my_keyspace-my_table-jb-51-Data.db (Too many open files)
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.CompressedRandomAccessReader.open(CompressedRandomAccessReader.java:47)
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.CompressedPoolingSegmentedFile.createReader(CompressedPoolingSegmentedFile.java:48)
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.PoolingSegmentedFile.getSegment(PoolingSegmentedFile.java:39)
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableReader.getFileDataInput(SSTableReader.java:1195)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.columniterator.SimpleSliceReader.<init>(SimpleSliceReader.java:57)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.columniterator.SSTableSliceIterator.createReader(SSTableSliceIterator.java:65)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.columniterator.SSTableSliceIterator.<init>(SSTableSliceIterator.java:42)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.filter.SliceQueryFilter.getSSTableColumnIterator(SliceQueryFilter.java:167)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.filter.QueryFilter.getSSTableColumnIterator(QueryFilter.java:62)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.CollationController.collectAllData(CollationController.java:250)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.CollationController.getTopLevelColumns(CollationController.java:53)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.getTopLevelColumns(ColumnFamilyStore.java:1550)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.getColumnFamily(ColumnFamilyStore.java:1379)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.Keyspace.getRow(Keyspace.java:327)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.SliceFromReadCommand.getRow(SliceFromReadCommand.java:65)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.pager.SliceQueryPager.queryNextPage(SliceQueryPager.java:77)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.pager.AbstractQueryPager.fetchPage(AbstractQueryPager.java:84)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.pager.SliceQueryPager.fetchPage(SliceQueryPager.java:33)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.pager.QueryPagers$1.next(QueryPagers.java:148)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/cassandra/data/my_keyspace/my_table/my_keyspace-my_table-jb-51-Data.db (Too many open files)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:233)
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.RandomAccessReader.<init>(RandomAccessReader.java:58)
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.CompressedRandomAccessReader.<init>(CompressedRandomAccessReader.java:76)
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.CompressedRandomAccessReader.open(CompressedRandomAccessReader.java:43)
    ... 28 more
```

Comment: There should be a more detailed exception message after the Exception in thread line. Please post the full stack trace, including the final "Caused by" entry, which gives the actual cause. Also, what release of DSE are you using? Thanks!

Comment: Added the full stack trace. There is no "caused by line" though. We are using DSE 4.0.0 but we have 2 nodes (including the new one) that are using 4.0.1 because your repo has already upgraded by the time that we provisioned the servers. The other node that is using 4.0.1 (node 5) bootstrapped successfully two weeks ago

Comment: There should be some indication of a problem on node 3 to match that connection problem. Was the exception on node 3 or node 1? IN any case, the problem indication should be on the other end from that exception report.

Comment: The exception is in node 3. In node 1, there is no indication of stream failure (seems like it's waiting for node 3 to continue sending files). The last line in node 1's system.log that mentions anything about node 3 is: "Prepare completed. Receiving 346 files(65880419359 bytes), sending 0 files(0 bytes)". Running "nodetool netstats" in node 1 shows a list of files (all 100%) under the IP of node 3 but the list is not changing anymore.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be very similar to a Cassandra bug/issue:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-6965

I'll follow up on that.

Meanwhile, you could run rebuild/repair on that new node.

EDIT: Another Cassandra issue that appears to be related:

CASSANDRA-6984 - "NullPointerException in Streaming During Repair"

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-6984
That issue is labeled as a Blocker, so it should get some prompt attention. I've inquired as to whether there is a workaround.

Stay tuned.

Comment: Either of the two (rebuild or repair) or both? Will this work even if the new node hasn't finished bootstrapping yet? (i.e. node is still shown as "joining" in opscenter and dsetool ring. Also, kindly note that we have another issue between node 4 and node 1 (see problem description in original post)

Comment: By the way, our cluster is currently in a partially upgraded state. Is it safe to run repair in the new node?

Comment: I tried "rebuild" just now, but it only streamed from one of the nodes where it has already streamed successfully before (node 5). No contact has been made with nodes 3 and 4

Comment: "repair" also doesn't work. It got stuck after the line "Starting repair command #1, repairing 1280 ranges for keyspace solr_admin". The data file sizes are not changing; and "AntiEntropyStage" in nodetool tpstats is 0

Answer (score 0):

> (Too many open files)

Looks like you need to increase your ulimit.